# How do I add a name for a constraint in Pyomo?

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I want to add names to my constraints so that it's easier to read the .lp / .gams files.
EDIT: Sorry if I hadn't mentioned, but I want to do this when a constraint list is initialized and constraints are added to it. Pyomo documentation has it only for normal constraints.
I was using PuLP before and was able to just add a string in the end of a constraint. Not sure how to do it with Pyomo. Documentation does not show it anywhere.

Comment: If you don’t receive an answer here, you might consider closing the question here and asking instead on the new [OR stack](https://or.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered on the Pyomo forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/pyomo-forum/5DgnivI1JRY